# 3-4 child windows in selenium by using getwindowhandles method

Tags: selenium, childwindow

I have a parent window, click on a link in parent window --> child window1 opens --> click on a link in child window1 --> child winodw2 opens --> click on a link in child window2 --> child window 3 opens --> click on a link in child window 3 --> child window 4 opens --> then return the control back to window4, window3, window2, window1 and parent window. Kindly help me on this using Selenium Webdriver in JAVA

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: To be frank, i am not supposed to post my code in any of the public sites. So consider this as one of the scenario and help me to find a way for this query.

Comment: @JeffC Take this as an scenario and provide the test script for the same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.getWindowHandles();//Return all open window handles
```

Loop through the windows as required for your case

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
}
```

If one window opens new window ,
You need to switch to second window.  Only from there you can click and goto third window.  Use the above steps.

Comment: I tried @giri but still am unable to move the control to second child. Could you pls share the code from ur perspective, so that i can get some idea

Comment: Giri can you please more elaborate on your comment ?? So that it will be useful for me to handle all the four Windows..